# Split output and rejoin again with named pipes on linux

Tags: linux, bash, fifo

My question is related to https://serverfault.com/questions/171095/how-do-i-join-two-named-pipes-into-single-input-stream-in-linux but with a slightly more convoluted setup.

I have three programs, `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3`;

`cmd1` takes no input and writes to stdout

`cmd2` reads stdin or a given file and writes to stdout

`cmd3` reads two files

The dataflow for these programs is the following: `cmd2` consumes data produced by `cmd1`, and `cmd3` consumes data produced by both `cmd1` and `cmd2`:

```
cmd1 ---+-----> cmd2 --->
        |                  cmd3
        +--------------->
```

How can I achieve this dataflow with a single command line using >(), pipes and `tee`?

My best guess is `cmd1 | tee >(cmd2) > >(cmd3)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [tee + cat: use an output several times and then concatenate results](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/66853)

Comment: or [Split an input for different command and combine the result](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/183356)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mkfifo thepipe
cmd3 <( cmd1 | tee thepipe ) <( cmd2 thepipe )
```

This uses a named pipe, `thepipe`, to transfer data between `tee` and `cmd2`.

Using your diagram:

```
cmd1 ---(tee)---(thepipe)--- cmd2 --->
          |                            cmd3
          +-------------------------->
```

Example with

- `cmd1` = `echo 'hello world'`, writes a string to standard output.
- `cmd2` = `rev`, reverses the order of characters on each line, reads a file or from standard input.
- `cmd3` = `paste`, takes input from two files (in this case) and produces two columns.

```
mkfifo thepipe
paste <( echo 'hello world' | tee thepipe ) <( rev thepipe )
```

Result:

```
hello world     dlrow olleh
```

The same thing, but putting the named pipe on the other branch in your diagram:

```
cmd1 ---(tee)--------------- cmd2 --->
          |                            cmd3
          +-----(thepipe)------------>
```

```
cmd3 thepipe <( cmd1 | tee thepipe | cmd2 )
```

With our example commands:

```
paste thepipe <( echo 'hello world' | tee thepipe | rev )
```

This produces the same output as above.

There are obviously other possibilities, such as

```
cmd1 | tee >( cmd2 >thepipe ) | cmd3 /dev/stdin thepipe
```

but I don't think you can get away from having to use a named pipe unless you're happy writing intermediate results to a temporary file and breaking it down into two sets of commands.